# How do I set a remote flash's power using Nikon CLS system?

Tags: nikon, flash, off-camera-flash, cls

I am using Nikon's CLS system to use the camera built-in flash as commander and the SB-910 flash as remote flash so I have set the SB-910 in remote mode and it does fire but I can't find a way to set its **power**! I can change its **zoom** in remote mode but not the power. So how I change the power in remote mode in this setup?
I can do it it Manual mode if I fire it with pocketwizerds

Comment: sorry mostly used to StackOverFlow for code :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You set the power from the custom menu  on your camera (menu item e3 on most models).  For each channel you can set exposure compensation to dial the power up/down

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can set Exposure Compensation directly on the speedlight. Second button from the left. Note that any EC set on camera is in addition to any EC set on the speedlight. Camera +1, speedlight -1 result is 0 EC.